# Camel processor unit/integration testing

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, apache-camel, spring-test

I've probably completly missed something but I can't manage to test my route as I want to.

I've got the following bean :

```
@Component("fileProcessor")
public class FileProcessor {
   public boolean valid(@Header("customObject) CustomObject customObject,Exchange exchange) throws IOException{
       return false;
}
```

I've a route calling my bean like so :

```
from("direct:validationFile").routeId("validationFile").validate().method("fileProcessor","valid")
        // Other stuff
        .end();
```

Here is my unit test, based on a example I found:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/tu-dao-beans.xml" })
public class FileProcessorTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @Override
    public boolean isDumpRouteCoverage() {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        String expectedBody = "<matched/>";
        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);
        template.sendBodyAndHeader(expectedBody, "foo", "bar");
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendNotMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(0);
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("<notMatched/>", "foo", "notMatchedHeaderValue");
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
//                from("direct:start").filter(header("foo").isEqualTo("bar")).to("mock:result");
                from("direct:start").routeId("validationFile").validate().method("fileProcessor","valid").to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The test fails because `fileProcessor` is not found, yet I'm pretty sure my `spring context`is properly loaded, I'm using the same `beans.xml`file for my `dbunit` tests and my DAO components are found just fine... What am I missing ?

EDIT:
Thanks to Jérémis B's answer I fixed my problem easily. In case someone stumble as I did here is the code I added:

```
@Autowired
private FileProcessor fileProcessor;

@Override
protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
    JndiRegistry registry = super.createRegistry();
    registry.bind("fileProcessor", fileProcessor);
    return registry;
}
```

Comment: I have published an article about this, hope it helps : https://dev.to/matthieusb/integration-testing-on-existing-routes-with-apache-camel-and-spring-and-dbunit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the [official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/spring-testing.html) for an "How to" test with Spring.

In your example, you create a Spring Context, but use the `CamelTestSupport` : This class create a CamelContext which is not aware of the Spring Context. The bean "fileProcessor" is not seen by this context.

There is a lot of ways to do this kind of test. The easiest, with the code you already have, is maybe to:

- Inject the fileProcessor in your test class, with @Autowire
- Override `createRegistry` and add the fileProcessor to the registry

You can too override `CamelSpringTestSupport` and implement `createApplicationContext`. Another way is to keep the route definition in a Spring Bean (through xml, or a RouteBuilder), and inject in your test `MockEndpoint`s or `ProducerTemplate`.